# Autofill contact form subject line (For Joomla 2.5)

Tags: joomla2.5, contact-form, autofill, subject

I would like to set up my contact form to automatically have a specific subject line added depending on which link is clicked.

I have found many explanations on how to do this in Joomla 1.5 (http://www.tall-paul.co.uk/2010/04/27/j ... act-email/) but when I open “components/com_contact/views/contact/tmpl/default_form.php” it looks different.

I have compared the code in "default_form.php" in my Joomla 2.5 site and an old install of Joomla 1.5 and they are quite different. Hence I am having trouble following all of the forums when they refer to the Joomla 1.5 file.

Can someone please show me how to manipulate the code in order to get the same effect as mentioned here (http://www.tall-paul.co.uk/2010/04/27/j ... act-email/) for Joomla 2.5?

Kind Regards,
Matt